# Magento Rest Api from Consumer key not found

Tags: magento-1.9, api, rest-api

I am requesting magento Rest api from my test file by appending consumer key and secret but after user login and authorization it shows consumer key not exist/found. I am passing consumer key as $_GET FROM MY form.

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below link for configuration of REST Api.

```
http://inchoo.net/magento/configure-magento-rest-and-oauth-settings/
```